# -webkit-border-radius looks ugly

Tags: html, safari, webkit, css

I'm styling a lightbox div with the following properties:

```
#lightbox {
  border: 0.3em solid #acaeb0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
  background: #eee -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 60%, 0% 100%, from(#eee), to(#ccc));
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0.6em 0.3em #888;
}
```

Problem is that the resulting rounded corners looks very ugly (using safari5):

[image]

Problem is the white space at the rounded corner.
Do you know how I can avoid this behavior?

EDIT:
After adding the `-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;` property it looks better but not perfect:

[image]

I reduced the width of the border but it looks the same with thick borders. Do I have to set another property to make it perfect looking?

EDIT2: 
Seems to be a Bug of webkit: 
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=21819

Comment: There are bunch of issues related to border-radius rendering in Webkit's bugzilla.

Comment: Stack Overflow has the same issue. Can't be helped.

Comment: Seems like the bug has been fixed since.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is called "background bleeding".

For a possible fix, take a look at this site: http://tumble.sneak.co.nz/post/928998513/fixing-the-background-bleed.

As it says, you should try setting:

```
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
```

Comment: hmm, added the `-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;` property and it seems to be better but not perfect, the effect is just reduced. Is there another property I have to set? See my origin post for the appearance after adding the new property.

Comment: I just wanted to thank you... using your suggestion I fixed a bug for which the Android browser didn't clip that background of an input box with rounded corners. :) So your fix does not just prevent the problem in the question, but also some variations.

Answer (score 2):

The only hack which gave me satisfaction on a similar case was to wrap a box within another : one with the background, the second with the border, both with the same border-radius but the first one with a transparent border. And the code comes like this :

```
.fist-block {background: black; border-radius: 20px; border: 0px solid transparent;}

.second-block {border-radius:20px; border: 1px solid red;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I get this problem in Chrome when using a 1px border however using 2px and above looks fine.
Chrome: 13.0.782.218 m